# Why do the left eye not wink anymore after I clicked the button

Tags: wpf, button, datatrigger

I made a button which have a yellow smiley as content. When the mouse enters the right eye should wink. When a boolean property change the value the left eye should wink. When I click this button both eyes should wink. With a second boolean property the color should change from yellow to red and the smiling mouth should change to a sad mouth. The mouse enter wink works fine. Also the boolean property changed trigger works fine until I click the button. When I click the button both eyes wink as they should. But after this the boolean property changed trigger do not work anymore!!!!

What made I wrong?
I have been dealing with this problem for more than a day.

```
<Button x:Name="buttonStartStop" Command="StartStop_Command" Grid.Column="1" Width="60" Margin="0, 4, 0, 0">
                <Button.Resources>
                    <Color x:Key="yellow">#FFFF00</Color>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="yellowSCB" Color="{StaticResource yellow}" />
                    <Color x:Key="red">#FF5050</Color>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="redSCB" Color="{StaticResource red}" />
                    <Color x:Key="black">#202020</Color>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="blackSCB" Color="{StaticResource black}" />
                    <Duration x:Key="dur">0:0:0.2</Duration>
                    <system:Double x:Key="smileySize">100.0</system:Double>
                    <system:Double x:Key="smileyEyeSize">20.0</system:Double>

                    <Storyboard x:Key="winkRight">
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="34" Storyboard.TargetName="eyeRight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="2" Storyboard.TargetName="eyeRight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.3" Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="25" Storyboard.TargetName="eyeRight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" />
                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.3" Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="{StaticResource smileyEyeSize}" Storyboard.TargetName="eyeRight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                    </Storyboard>

                    <Storyboard x:Key="winkLeftB">
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="34" Storyboard.TargetName="eyeLeft" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="2" Storyboard.TargetName="eyeLeft" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.3" Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="25" Storyboard.TargetName="eyeLeft" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" />
                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.3" Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="{StaticResource smileyEyeSize}" Storyboard.TargetName="eyeLeft" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                    </Storyboard>

                    <Storyboard x:Key="winkLeft">
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="34" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.3" Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" />
                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.3" Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="{StaticResource smileyEyeSize}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                    </Storyboard>

                </Button.Resources>
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Border x:Name="background" Background="#AAAAAA" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4">
                                        <Viewbox Margin="1">
                                            <Canvas Width="{StaticResource smileySize}" Height="{StaticResource smileySize}">
                                                <Ellipse x:Name="smiley" Width="{StaticResource smileySize}" Height="{StaticResource smileySize}" Fill="{StaticResource yellowSCB}" >
                                                    <Ellipse.Style>
                                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
                                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HeadlineValues.Explode}" Value="True">
                                                                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="{StaticResource red}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(Color)" />
                                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="{StaticResource yellow}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(Color)" />
                                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                                                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </Ellipse.Style>
                                                    <Ellipse.Effect>
                                                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="0" Color="{Binding Path=Fill.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Ellipse}}" />
                                                    </Ellipse.Effect>
                                                </Ellipse>
                                                <Ellipse x:Name="eyeLeft" Width="{StaticResource smileyEyeSize}" Height="{StaticResource smileyEyeSize}" Fill="{StaticResource blackSCB}" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="25">
                                                    <Ellipse.Style>
                                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
                                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HeadlineValues.FieldClick}" Value="True">
                                                                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource winkLeft}" />
                                                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HeadlineValues.FieldClick}" Value="True">
                                                                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                                                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource winkLeft}" />
                                                                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </Ellipse.Style>
                                                </Ellipse>
                                                
                                                <Ellipse x:Name="eyeRight" Width="{StaticResource smileyEyeSize}" Height="{StaticResource smileyEyeSize}" Fill="{StaticResource blackSCB}" Canvas.Left="60" Canvas.Top="25" />
                                                
                                                <Path Stroke="{StaticResource blackSCB}" StrokeThickness="10" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round">
                                                    <Path.Style>
                                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
                                                            <Setter Property="Data">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero">
                                                                        <PathFigure StartPoint="20, 65" IsClosed="False" IsFilled="False">
                                                                            <BezierSegment Point1="20, 65" Point2="50, 100" Point3="80, 65" />
                                                                        </PathFigure>
                                                                    </PathGeometry>
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HeadlineValues.Explode}" Value="True">
                                                                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                                <PointAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="30, 75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Data.(PathGeometry.Figures)[0].(PathFigure.StartPoint)" />
                                                                                <PointAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="30, 75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Data.(PathGeometry.Figures)[0].(PathFigure.Segments)[0].(BezierSegment.Point1)" />
                                                                                <PointAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="50, 55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Data.(PathGeometry.Figures)[0].(PathFigure.Segments)[0].(BezierSegment.Point2)" />
                                                                                <PointAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="70, 75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Data.(PathGeometry.Figures)[0].(PathFigure.Segments)[0].(BezierSegment.Point3)" />
                                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                                <PointAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="20, 65" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Data.(PathGeometry.Figures)[0].(PathFigure.StartPoint)" />
                                                                                <PointAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="20, 65" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Data.(PathGeometry.Figures)[0].(PathFigure.Segments)[0].(BezierSegment.Point1)" />
                                                                                <PointAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="50, 100" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Data.(PathGeometry.Figures)[0].(PathFigure.Segments)[0].(BezierSegment.Point2)" />
                                                                                <PointAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="80, 65" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Data.(PathGeometry.Figures)[0].(PathFigure.Segments)[0].(BezierSegment.Point3)" />
                                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                                                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </Path.Style>
                                                </Path>
                                            </Canvas>
                                        </Viewbox>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource winkRight}" />
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="#BBBBBB" Storyboard.TargetName="background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="{StaticResource dur}" To="#AAAAAA" Storyboard.TargetName="background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource winkRight}" />
                                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource winkLeftB}" />
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
```

Comment: Works for me just fine however i removed your command because it gave me an error.
Maybe check what you do in that command might be the issue there

Comment: In the command I forgot the binding.
At me it is working until lI press the button. I see the wink on both eyes but after this only the right eye winks again.

Comment: @gFort It is still unclear what you want to happen. When I take your code and comment out the command binding, this is what happens. When the mouse is over the button, the right eye blinks. When you click the button, both eyes blink.  The missing piece for us to help you is for you to share your StartStop_Command code, your HeadlineValues code, and to explain clearly what action isn't working for you. Saying "But after this the boolean property changed trigger do not work anymore" doesn't mean anything to me.  What ACTION doesn't work anymore?

Comment: Hello, Yes it works fine. But when I click the button and the command was triggered then the left eye will not work anymore. It works only when I start the application until I press the button. Only the left eye. The lright eye works fine all time.